# Select drop down options adding special characters

Tags: javascript, html, angular, utf-8, character-encoding

I am displaying select drop down options by fetching option descriptions from database, few options are adding special characters &#147 instead of '-'

Comment: can you post an example of your code, so we can see your progress so far?, :)

Comment: Other options in the dropdown are displayed normally, but the option with "-" in them is displayed as  â&#147

Comment: of course, but how was this option fetched from the database ?, which database are you using ? for me it looks like an encoding error, propaply someone isn't running in utf-8 mode. but i wish you could provide us more information about it, so we can give you best asnwers

Comment: I am using angular with postgresql